# Am struggling to edit the DOM elements of my pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I debug a third party JavaScript plugin.

I am using a [plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/content-timeline-jqueryhtml5css3-plugin/2617834) called content timeline and that used JavaScript to display posts.

So, I want to target a heading that shows the timeline month, but for some reason, nothing works on any element.

Tried this:

```
$("h4.t_line_month").addClass('example');
```

However, if I add

```
console.log("the script works");
```

I see the message in the console.

Unfortunately, there is nothing much I can tell other than the fact that I am not being able to access the plugin elements for some reason.
Are there ways that I use to debug this?
perhaps some rule being set in WordPress or in the plugin itself.

Have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: That seems a basic jQuery syntax for adding a class to element, what does that have to do with the plugin you are using? Does the class get added or not? Also question is really vague "nothing works on any element" what does that mean?

Comment: @Esko I assume it has to do with the plugin because  I can add a class to any other elements in the site that has nothing to do with the same plugin

Comment: Just a guess: Maybe the plugins loads content dynamically, so the element h4.t_line_month is not present at the time you try to query it or does not have the class 't_line_month' in this very moment.

Comment: OP, is this the plugin you use? https://codecanyon.net/item/content-timeline-jqueryhtml5css3-plugin/2617834 You should add the plugin link to your question to provide more information.

Comment: I thought about that, and added my code inside a settimeout which gives 5 seconds for the code to execute....but still no success.
I also used esprima.org to double check on syntax errors and all seems to be ok

Comment: @blaz yes that is the one and I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQyery each() function to itterate all of the h4 tags on your page to see if its even there.

```
$('.testimonial').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html()); // debug to see which is which
});
```

Also if the WP plugin you are using is creating an iFrame... this could be the cause of you not being able to directly access the element you need.

Comment: Not sure about .testimonial class, but I changed that to h1 and the console gave the html/content inside the h1 of the page that was loaded